# reading a plist to an NSMutableArray without using initWithContentsOfFile

Tags: iphone, ios, file, nsmutablearray, plist

I have a NSMutableArray which repeatedly will be filled with the changing contents of a plist. How do I do this most efficiently? 
I know I could use a second NSArray which I alloc initWithContentsOfFile and then arrayWithArray, but isn't there method to directly load the contents of a file without init (thinking of performance). Just curious.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Loading from a file will be the performance bottleneck for you, not initialising a new array. Do you actually have a performance problem or are you prematurely optimising?

Comment: Prematurely optimizing. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *coolArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:@"plist path"];
```

Comment: Note that this is quite probably doing exactly the same thing as initWithContentsOfFile.

Comment: Brilliant, exactly what I was looking for. I admit that I forgot to search the documentation in NSArray... Thanks!

Comment: @jrturton: it pretty much is, minus the dev having to do the alloc and then cast it from a NSArray to a mutable one, which is part of the problem the OP was referencing. But this is how you get data from a plist, so not much to do about it.